# ssl peer unverified exception LIFElog api

Tags: sony, sony-lifelog-api

I am getting ssl peer unverified error while fetching AccessToken from lifelog api.
I am able to get the auth_code from the callback URL, but when I am trying to get Access_Token it is giving me SSL peer Unverified exception. 
Does I have to add any certificate to android device?
Please give the Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any chance you are using HttpClient to connect to Lifelog? This problem has appeared before because of the use of HttpClient. It looks like Google has removed support for this call in Android 6.0.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

You should be able to use HttpsURLConnection instead of Httpclient to access the Lifelog Web Service.